# Is passing by reference makes php define the undefined parameters?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I don't understand this behavior, here is my code

**Case1 - passing by values**

```
<?php
testReference($var);
var_dump($var);
die("<br>end");

function testReference($var)
{
    return;
}
```

this outputs :

> Notice: Undefined variable: var in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.SE.php on
>   line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: var in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.SE.php on
>   line 3
>
> NULL
>
> end

**Case2 - passing by reference(same code except the '&')**

```
<?php
testReference($var);
var_dump($var);
die("<br>end");

function testReference(&$var) //<- difference
{
    return;
}
```

this outputs :

> NULL
>
> end

as you see using a var after passing it to a function by reference stops the Undefined variable Notice from showing.

**is passing by reference makes php define the undefined parameters internally?. and if so, is this a trusty behavior that I can depend on for defining vars that I'm not sure if they are set or not?.** for example:

can I do this? :

```
validateInput($POST['Unreliable']); //<- by reference
echo $POST['Unreliable'];
```

instead of this

```
validateInput($POST['Unreliable']);
if(isset($POST['Unreliable'])){
    echo $POST['Unreliable'];
}
```

Comment: variables Scope !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a very strange approach. Why not just `if (isset(field)) { runValidate(field) }`?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh . I'm sorry I'm not sure of what you mean? . do you ask about the variable scope? this is the only code that reproduce the behavior. global variable passed to a function.

Comment: @u_mulder  less verbale(code). I'm making a class that validate the client inputs . and I like the code more when it is shorter and do the same thing

Comment: Code is for people. Making code less verbale and less understandable is not a good approach again.

Comment: @u_mulder OK. and what about that behavior. Why php didn't show the notice after passing it to a function by reference ?

Comment: @Accountantم I mean in your first observation there is variable scope issue. In your second line you are passing a variable `$var` to testReference which is not defined.. and in third line is same, you are trying to `var_dumping` a variable which is not defined...

Comment: @ManpreetSingh yes, I know that . what I don't understand is why the errors didn't show in the second case **-which is exactly case1 except for that the `$var` is passed by reference-**

Comment: My guess is that when you pass a variable by reference, PHP internally increments a use counter for that variable. This could cause it to see that variable as being in existence

Answer (score 0):

If you get an undefined variable by reference, the undefined variable will be created and set to NULL, which makes sense. It has to exist to be referenced and it hasn't been set to anything else, so it is NULL.

```
$ref = &$undef;
var_dump($undef); // outputs NULL
```

So yes, I think it is safe to count on this.